# No DC convergence issue

Tags: dc, flipflop, nmos, ads

I am simulating a circuit consists of a clock, a NMOS, and a D flipflop.
I wonder why it gave me the error no DC convergence? How should I fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The software can't find an equilibrium starting point, probably something to do with the flipflop. There might be a way to tell it, for example, that Vout starts low. Or maybe it is confused about the input to the NOT gate, which isn't attached to any output.

Comment: gibai you should [take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to recognize the importance of marking the completion of Q&A sessions that have acceptable answers. Yes this site is free and you don't have to upvote or accept answers but, do you want anyone to think you are mean or ungrateful. You have asked 13 questions now and surely there must be some with an acceptable answer? I have mentioned this to you a few times before today.

Answer (score 0):

When the FET gate is low, its drain node is undetermined because it only connects to logic gate inputs. And since the simulation assumes ideal components, there's nothing to determine that node voltage. That's what is making the math unable to converge.

In a real circuit, there would be some leakage currents that would determine the voltage.
Try adding a resistor R=100kOhm between FET drain and logic high power supply, to give the simulation something to drive that indeterminate node. The exact value isn't critical, it's just one way of modelling an input leakage current present in real logic gates. (Usually a circuit designer would try to avoid depending on that leakage current to determine the voltage.)

Additionally, it's also possible that the perfect symmetry of the D flip flop is preventing it from converging. You can help it along by adding some asymmetry, to make it prefer to come up in either the 0 state or the 1 state.

Often when there are simulation problems, you can help the simulation converge by adding components to model the practical, non-ideal effects of real components.

Comment: yeah after I add the resistance between source and drain of the NMOS, things starts to work fine. many thanks.